# mute built-in speakers without muting external output speakers/headphones from command line

Tags: sound, volume-control, speakers, mute

I have been looking for an answer for this and couldn't find one. I am trying to mute/un-mute the built-in speakers of my computer from the command line without affecting  the external speakers connected to the output jack of the sound card.

So far I found these commands to mute/un-mute from the command line, but both commands also mute/un-mute the external speakers:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 1 0

amixer sset Speaker mute
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a dell optiplex 760 Pentium 4

The sink 0 device is the HDMI audio output of the nVidia video card, but I'm not interested in that one for this script.

It seems the sink 1 device controls both the builtin speakers and the external output speakers. I can´t find a way to distinguish between both. Any ideas?

If you need more information that can point me to a solution please let me know.

Comment: Can external and internal speakers be on at the same time?

Comment: @Volker No. You have to chose which output to use: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kIk6m.png

Comment: Can you open `pavucontrol`? Maybe you need to install it.

Comment: On the output tab, I have separate controls for two devices, inclusive mute.

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. I found the solution to my problem but can´t post it until a couple of hours because of my newbie reputation. i have to wait a couple more hours to be able to post it

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Yes, in my case, internal and external speakers can be on at the same time. Probably because Im using the built in soundcard. And yes, from the GUI I can mute/unmute the devices separately, but I needed to be able to do it from the command line.

Comment: Ok, good! And for command line tool: I'm sure it can be done with `pactl` - but it's a little scary ;) `pactl list` did irritate me a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **command line** interface of **pulseaudio**, you can list all sinks (as in "places where sound stream goes away") like this:

`pactl list short sinks`

```
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.1.hdmi-stereo   module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
1 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz RUNNING
```

Now, you can work with the separate sinks, and have all the details.

You can use the full name of the sink as arument:

```
`pactl set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo toggle`
```

You can **instead** of the **long name**, use the **index number** listed in front of the name (`1`):

**Toggle mute**, that is switch between sound on and off:
    `pactl set-sink-mute 1 toggle`

Switch **mute on**, that is sound off:
    `pactl set-sink-mute 1 1`

Switch **mute off**, that is sound on:
    `pactl set-sink-mute 1 0`

See `pactl help` or `man pactl` for more options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works perfectly when the output devices are in different sinks. The problem I had is that the outputs I want to toggle are 2 different ports of the same sink. To differentiate them I used the command "pacmd list-cards". At the bottom it lists the different ports for the sink. Then I activate the one that I want with "pacmd set-sink-port SINK PORT_NAME". In my case I had ports named: analog-output-speaker and analog-output-headphones for the same sink. By activating analog-output-headphones, it disables the builtin audio, which is what I needed

Comment: Looking at the output of `pacmd list-cards` - interesting, I see various ports too... You could make a self-answer from this, if it may be helpful for others? I think it is! Should I integrate it into the end of my answer? Seems useful, I think. I learned already from it.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. If you want you can add it to your answer. It could probably help others as well. I still can´t post an answer to the question so if you could add it to your answer it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, we can just wait, and then you make it a full answer. (Now I remember, there is some self-answer wait period - that does not depend on reputation points). But if you edit your own question - that should work allways, I think - and add a section at the bottom, marked with "draft answer - will be added to answer below", I will move it over and integrate it.